# merging <td> rows in one column of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement, if i have same data in column1 of 's with same id then i need to merge those cells and show their respective values in column2.
i.e., in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7t9qkLc0/12/  the **key** column have 3rows with data 1 as row value with same id and has corresponding different values in **Value** column i.e., AA,BB,CC. I want to merge the 3 rows in **key** Column and display data 1 only once and show their corresponding values in separate rows in **value** column.
Similarly for data4 and data5 the values are same i.e.,FF and keys are different, i want to merge last 2 rows in Value column and dispaly FF only one time and show corresponding keys in key column. All data i'm getting would be the dynamic data. Please suggest. 
Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7t9qkLc0/12/

Sample html code:

```
<table width="300px" height="150px" border="1">
<tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>                            
<tr>
<td id="1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
<td id="aa">AA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
<td id="bb">BB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
<td id="cc">CC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="2">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
<td id="dd">DD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="2">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
<td id="ee">EE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="3">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3</td>
<td id="ff">FF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="4">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4</td>
<td id="ff">FF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="5">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5</td>
<td id="ff">FF</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple ids with the same value. Neither is just a number a valid id.

Comment: As @PeeHaa said, you should not use the same `ID` multible times in a document. Instead use class or **data attributes**.. which is `data-id` instead of `id`.

Comment: @user4199704, if you are getting your data from a database, are yo then able to modify whether or not the data is rendered/written as markup in the first place?

Comment: if so, the solution may drastically different, for writing the data into a JSON object and creating a table from that data would be preferable then modify the DOM (by virtue of modifying the table).

Answer (score 2):

Building on tkounenis' answer using Rowspan:

One option to implement what you need would be to read all the values in your table after being populated, then use a JS object literal as a data structure to figure out what rows/columns are unique.

A JS object literal requires a unique key which you can map values to.  After figuring out what rows/columns should be grouped, you can either edit the original table, or hide the original table and create a new table (I'm creating new tables in this example).

I've created an example for you to create a new table either grouped by key or grouped by value.  Try to edit the examples provided to introduce both requirements.

Let me know if you need more help.  Best of luck.

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/x417905v/

JS (uses jQuery):

```
sortByCol(0);
sortByCol(1);

function sortByCol(keyCol) {
    // keyCol = 0 for first col, 1 for 2nd col
    var valCol = (keyCol === 0) ? 1 : 0;
    var $rows = $('#presort tr');
    var dict = {};
    var col1name = $('th').eq(keyCol).html();
    var col2name = $('th').eq(valCol).html();

    for (var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i++) {

        if ($rows.eq(i).children('td').length > 0) {

            var key = $rows.eq(i).children('td').eq(keyCol).html();
            var val = $rows.eq(i).children('td').eq(valCol).html();

            if (key in dict) {
                dict[key].push(val);
            } else {
                dict[key] = [val];
            }
        }
    }
    redrawTable(dict,col1name,col2name);
}


function redrawTable(dict,col1name,col2name) {
    var $table = $('<table>').attr("border",1);
    $table.css( {"width":"300px" } );
    $table.append($('<tr><th>' +col1name+ '</th><th>' +col2name+ '</th>'));

    for (var prop in dict) {
        for (var i = 0, len = dict[prop].length; i< len; i++) {

          var $row = $('<tr>');

          if ( i == 0) {
            $row.append( $("<td>").attr('rowspan',len).html( prop ) );
            $row.append( $("<td>").html( dict[prop][i] ) ); 
          }
          else {
            $row.append( $("<td>").html( dict[prop][i] ) ); 
          }
          $table.append($row);
        }

    }
    $('div').after($table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rowspan` attribute like so:

```html
<table width="300px" height="150px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="1" rowspan="3">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
        <td id="aa">AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="bb">BB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cc">CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="2" rowspan="2">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
        <td id="dd">DD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="ee">EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="3">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3</td>
        <td id="ff">FF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="4">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4</td>
        <td id="ff">FF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="5">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5</td>
        <td id="ff">FF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm looking for javascript where it dynamically adds the rowspan, because my data is getting from database and id value also i get from database and at the time of display i dont know how many elements have same id.@tkounenis. Thanks.

Comment: I rephrased the question.
Apart from the dynamic nature of the data, his second condition was a groupby on the second column, or value column.. so a row span on the second column would have been more or less neccessary to show in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/37b793pz/4/

Can not be used more than once the same id. For that use data-id attribute

**HTML:**

```
<table width="300px" height="150px" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
        <td data-id="valaa">AA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
        <td data-id="valbb">BB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key1">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
        <td data-id="valcc">CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key2">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
        <td data-id="valdd">DD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key2">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
        <td data-id="valee">EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key3">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3</td>
        <td data-id="valff">FF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key4">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4</td>
        <td data-id="valff">FF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="key5">data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5</td>
        <td data-id="valff">FF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JQ:**

```
//merge cells in key column
function mergerKey() {    

    // prevents the same attribute is used more than once Ip
    var idA = [];

    // finds all cells id column Key
    $('td[data-id^="key"]').each(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        // prevents the same attribute is used more than once IIp
        if ($.inArray(id, idA) == -1) {
            idA.push(id);

            // finds all cells that have the same data-id attribute
            var $td = $('td[data-id="' + id + '"]');

            //counts the number of cells with the same data-id
            var count = $td.size();
            if (count > 1) {

                //If there is more than one
                //then merging                    
                $td.not(":eq(0)").remove();
                $td.attr('rowspan', count);
            }
        }
    })
}

//similar logic as for mergerKey()
function mergerVal() {
    var idA = [];
    $('td[data-id^="val"]').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        if ($.inArray(id, idA) == -1) {
            idA.push(id);
            var $td = $('td[data-id="' + id + '"]');
            var count = $td.size();
            if (count > 1) {

                $td.not(":eq(0)").remove();
                $td.attr('rowspan', count);
            }
        }
    })
}

mergerKey();
mergerVal();
```

Comment: I want similar kind of output.But issue here is in jquery function you have manually checked the condition as 'td[data-id^="key" ,but for me i don't know what would be the key value i'm getting as they are dynamic and retrieved from database , my code would look some thing as : <td data-id=${object.key}>data1</td>.  Please suggest,thanks. @dm4web

Comment: key word indicates that cells belonging to the column key. in your case, define your data-id by adding the word key + object.key

Comment: Please see my table structure in http://jsfiddle.net/37b793pz/5/. Somehow the alignment is not proper. I used the same jquery as suggested. Is the div tag causing me the issue, please suggest, thanks. @dm4web

Comment: The problem is that cells with the same data-id are not grouped. You have a data-id = "key13" data-id = "key12" data-id = "key11" data-id = "key13" data-id = "key12". To mergerkey() worked should go like eg : data-id = "key13" data-id = "key13" data-id = "key11" data-id = "key12" data-id = "key12 ". There are two solutions: 1. change the order of the print table rows. 2, to sort the rows using Jquery and then call mergerkey()

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet of javascript. It should work fine for what you are looking.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function mergeCommonCells(table, columnIndexToMerge){
         previous = null;
            cellToExtend = null;
            table.find("td:nth-child("+columnIndexToMerge+")").each(function(){
                jthis = $(this);
                content = jthis.text();
                if(previous == content){
                    jthis.remove();
                    if(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan") == undefined){
                        cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", 2);
                    }
                    else{
                        currentrowspan = parseInt(cellToExtend.attr("rowspan"));
                        cellToExtend.attr("rowspan", currentrowspan+1);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    previous = content;
                    cellToExtend = jthis;
                }
            });
        };

        mergeCommonCells($("#tableId"), 1);
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```